# Отправка push-уведомления Firebase Cloud Messaging не из консоли

Tags: android, firebase

Попробовал прикрутить к своему Android-приложению FCM, частично получилось - при создании уведомления в консоли Firebase уведомления приходят на девайс, однако хочу чтобы при определенном действии в приложении на остальные девайсы отсылалось push-уведомление об этом действии.

Для начала я решил использовать **CURL** для симуляции отправки сообщений, по логам сообщения обрабатываются в методе *onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)*, однако **push-уведомления не появляются.**

Сервис в **AndroidManifest**

```
<service android:name=".Service.MessagingService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

При регистрации подписываю устройства на канал "test"

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("test");
```

Метод **onMessageReceived**

```
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
   showNotification (remoteMessage.getData().get("title"), remoteMessage.getData().get("context"));
}
```

Отправляю запрос через PHP-скрипт

```
<?php
// API access key from Google API's Console
define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'AIzaSyB4ZanJWaCay_fXxO5z0jI55T8UOwdGNNQ' );

// prep the bundle
$msg = array
(
    'user'      => 'somebody',
    'title'     => 'This is a title. title',
    'context'   => 'here is a message. message',
    'vibrate'   => 1,
    'sound'     => 1
);

$fields = array
(
    'to'            => '/topics/test',
    'data'          => $msg
);

$headers = array
(
    'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
$result = curl_exec($ch );
curl_close( $ch );
echo $result;
?>
```

Выполняя этот запрос получаю

```
{"message_id":5069819597562559135}
```

Причем данные, которые отправляются в запросе, **приложение получает**, но push-уведомление отсутствует. Из-за чего от моих запросов не появляются push-уведомления?

Comment: Наверное showNotification проблемный. Попробуйте до 8  версии ОС ваш код запустить

Comment: @ЮрийСПб метод отрабатывает отлично, исключений не возникает, выводил содержимое remoteMessage в конце метода. Попробую запустить на более ранней версии ОС - отпишу

Comment: @ЮрийСПб на 7.1.1 уведомления приходят, но что делать с остальными версиями?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему, оказывается на ОС версии ниже **8** все работает прекрасно, но выше **работать не будет** (без дополнительных телодвижений).

В **8** версии андроида добавили такую штуку как **"Каналы"**. Если ваше уведомление не относится ни к одному из каналов - **оно не отобразится**. Почитать поподробнее можно **[вот тут](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#ManageChannels)**.

Починил свою проблему следующим образом:

1. Добавил название канала в ресурсы

```
<string name="default_notification_channel_id" translatable="false">fcm_default_channel</string>
```

2. Добавил мета-данные в манифест проекта

```
<application>
...
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
    android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id"/>
</application>
```

3. Теперь перед вызовом уведомления (**notificationManager.notify**) будем присваивать уведомлению наш канал

```
...настройка notificationManager

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    String channelId = context.getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id);
    NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,   title, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
    channel.setDescription(body);
    mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    builder.setChannelId(channelId);
}

notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
```